# Mapping of $S_4$ and checking to see the cycles

Tags: group-theory

My question is: is every element of $S_4$ a cycle?

I say yes by taking the identity mapping, every element in $S_4 = (1)(2)(3)(4)$

Need verification.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean is part of a cycle?

Comment: @rlartiga  i mean every element in S_4 will form a cycle.

Comment: $S_4$ has $24$ elements.  You are looking at elements of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: So does all the elements will form a cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map which simultaneously switches 1,2 and switches 3,4 is not a cycle.

In cycle notation this map is $(12)(34),$ and it is a product of *two* different cycles, each being a 2-cycle or "transposition". In fact $4$ is the smallest $n$ for which $S_n$ contains any non-cycle permutations, there not being enough room if $n\le 3$ to make an example.

Clarification: A "cycle" is a map which starts at one thing and keeps mapping to the next, eventually getting back to the start, and which has no effect on other letters. For example in $S_4$ there is the map $1 \to 3 \to 4 \to 1$ which is $(134)$ in cycle notation [which assumes the last thing in the cycle maps back to the first, otherwise each thing to the next]. This map $(134)$ as a cycle is assumed not to move anything other than the terms mentioned in the cycle. So even if it were regarded as a cycle in $S_5$ one could not include $(25)$ at the end, and $(134)(25)$ would not be a cycle.

Comment: i need more clarification on the answer provided.

Comment: @Lynnie Just added some clarification. But maybe you could say are you in an abstract algebra course, and if so have they defined cycle notation yet?

Comment: @ coffeemath thanks